# Website doesn't fit fully screen on iPhone

Tags: html, ios, iphone, css

I got a website [click here to goto website](http://forumsec.org/index2.cfm), it actually doesn't seem to fit the iPhone screen. Please [click here to goto the iPhone 4 Simulator](http://forumsec.org/index2.cfm)

I have tired

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=320, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
<meta name="viewport" width="device-width">
```

This doesn't seems to work for me. Any help please?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue you are having is not in your `<meta name="viewport">` element. You need to make your website responsive, I recommend you use `@media` queries to work your websites responsiveness to each type of device.

Comment: The website design is so complicate to make the website responsive. Thats why I just wanted to fit to the screen.

Comment: @NavneilNaicker Well this is exactly what you need to fix your issue, It is not that complicated to design a website to be responsive, I recommend you really look into doing this, especially because in the long run you can gain traffic if your site is friendly to those who visit via laptop, or iPhone. I would appreciate this answer being selected if you found it helpful, always helps to the person who answers. This is the only way I would recommend fixing your problem.

Comment: Thanks PatchGuru, Let me check it out what I do about this.